# Is possible to have UserInfo.getUserId() as null?

Tags: apex, userinfo

I am wondering if there is any scenario where `UserInfo.getUserId()` will return `null`?

Will the following SOQL always return some row?

```java
User user = [SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there will always be a non-`null` User Id.

However, there are other things you might think are invariant that aren't: for example, the "ghost user" that runs package push upgrades and postinstall scripts doesn't have a Profile (`ProfileId` is `null`). This can result in surprising and very difficult-to-debug exceptions.